# How to use regex to check if two characters exist in string no matter their location

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to convert csv imported numbers from (5.25) to -5.25 to be imported into a DB.

```
$CSV[] = 'abcd';
$CSV[] = '(5.25)';
foreach($CSV as $Record){
    if(preg_match_all("/[()]/", $Record, $output_array)){
        $Record = '-' . preg_replace("/[()]/", '', $Record);
    }
}
```

However, because i need to run this conversion on each record in the csv,  and we don't know if the data in the column will be a number or some text, I need to only convert the string if both characters are present and wrapping the number.

Is this the proper way to use preg_match and preg_replace? It seems to be returning true to everything and essentially adding a dash "-" to every csv column.

Comment: You don't need a regular expression. You can check the first and last character for `"("` and `")"`. If you need to check for actual numbers (which your code doesn't do) you can write it like `/^\([0-9.]+\)$/`

Comment: @Halcyon thats a much better idea, so ill check the first and last character of the string and i should also check if the string contains numbers. `if($Record[0] == '(' && $Record[strlen($Record) - 1] == ')' && preg_match('/^\([0-9.]+\)$/', $Record, $matches) == true){
 $Record = '-' . preg_replace("/[()]/", '', $Record);
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want something like this:

```
$CSV[] = 'abcd';
$CSV[] = '(5.25)';
$Record = array();
foreach($CSV as $value){
        $Record[] = preg_replace("/\(([^a-zA-Z]+?)\)/", '-$1', $value);
}
var_dump($Record);
```

Comment: also regex can be like  `/\(([0-9.,]+?)\)/` for accept numbers,period(.) and comma(,)

Comment: you don't need to use `preg_match_all` with this code

Answer (score 0):

```
(\s|^)⇢(\s|$)|(\s|^)⇠(\s|$)
```

Searches if character ⇢ or ⇠ exists